# Make variables in settings.py configurable in Django admin site

Tags: python-3.x, django

In my deployed Django web backend application, some variables (e.g. react_app_url, log_level) are specified in settings.py.

I can reconfigure them and make them effective by relaunching the Django app. But the relaunching procedure pauses the whole service and can affect others who is interacting with the Django APIs.

It is possible to configure those variables during run time via the Django admin site?

updates:
According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code), it is not recommended to alter variables in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an app named `core` which contains model `Config`, and you want to modify "config" in admin page.
So you have to take care 2 things:

1. Load Config to `settings` when the project up.
2. Update `settings` when config was updated.

My idea is use `apps.ready` and model signal to do all thing above.

In `core/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = "core.apps.CoreConfig"
```

In `core/apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
        # set all your value from Config model to settings here
```

In `core/signals.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver, Signal

from core.models import Config

@receiver(post_save, sender=Config)
def update_config_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Update your settings value here
    # settings.VALUE = instance.value
    pass
```

Comment: one minor issue: ready(self) function needs to be indented.